# Error while trying to schedule a recipe for local data sync

Tags: einstein-analytics, tableau-crm, crm-analytics

I have an opportunity and user-based recipes in the system, and I want to enable a local data sync to it.

When I navigate to the data manager tab and try to schedule a recipe based on an event with the "The salesforce local connection syncs" option, the system throws an error: "ALL_SALESFORCE_OBJECTS isn't a valid trigger rule for an event-based schedule."

Can someone help me understand this error? I want to run a recipe every time local data changes.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for isn't actually supported by CRM Analytics.

The Event-Based schedule is meant to be used for triggering dataflows after a Salesforce Local Connection syncs, not for kicking off a local connection when Salesforce data changes. These connections can be scheduled to run by the minute, hour, week or month, but you should consider how much of a latency is actually acceptable.

When you consider the resources that this would require and the potential (in fact likelihood) that you would constantly have your local connection queued to sync this makes sense.

References:

- [Schedule Data Sync to Run Automatically](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bi_integrate_schedule_replication.htm&type=5)
- [Run, Schedule and Sync CRM Analytics Data with REST APIs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_rest.meta/bi_dev_guide_rest/bi_run_schedule_sync_data.htm)